# SignIn Google button crash with Swift 3

Tags: cocoapods, swift3, google-signin

I had my iOS app almost ready for going out but I have the most awful idea... going for Swift 3. Since then everything has gone wrong.

Now that I have cleaned the most obvious bugs and problems, I can't find the solution for this problem: When I press the SignInButton for initiating a Google Session my app crash.
In the debug navigation window shows:

```
*0- objc_exception_throw
1- +[NSException raise:format]
2- [GIDSignIn SignInWithOptions:]
3- [GIDSignInButton pressed]*
```

I have installed the Google SignIn via CocoaPods and the previous step of "connecting" with the Google part in the AppDelegate seems to work ok.

Has anyone problems with this GoogleSignIn Button in Swift 3? Any suggestions? Thanks everybody in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give too few information, but, if the debugger stops showing a call to `objc_exception_throw`, there should be more information in the Console on the Debug Area panel.

If you can't see that information, make sure you don't have a breakpoint active for "All Exceptions". In that case, disable the breakpoint, try again, and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have disable "All Exceptions" breakpoint and I figured out that I had a problem with the Google Id (some misunderstanding between programmers of different platforms). I am going to check right now if it works properly with the new Id.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google SignIn is unopen source code so you don't get to see under the hood even if you enable `All Exception` breakpoint. So what you are reporting debug stack is correct.

This happen to me missing Google SignIn requirement. My case I had multiple targets and forgot to have a Google URL scheme from Google SignIn Setting.

1. **Copy URL Scheme provided from Google Sign**
2. **Select Target**
3. **Paste onto Info-> URL Types '+'**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The information you have given is too less. But still make sure you have done these things.

You should have added URL schemes as shown in the below image. 
[image]

In your AppDelegate Class make sure you have added the following function

```
//this function is added only
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

And for ViewController or where you have added the Button the code should be like the following

import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

```
//label to display name of logged in user
@IBOutlet weak var labelUserEmail: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //error object
    var error : NSError?

    //setting the error
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&error)

    //if any error stop execution and print error
    if error != nil{
        print(error ?? "google error")
        return
    }


    //adding the delegates
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    //getting the signin button and adding it to view
    let googleSignInButton = GIDSignInButton()
    googleSignInButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(googleSignInButton)

}

//when the signin complets
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    //if any error stop and print the error
    if error != nil{
        print(error ?? "google error")
        return
    }

    //if success display the email on label 
    labelUserEmail.text = user.profile.email
}
```

}

It should work this way with Swift 3.

Reference: **[Google Sign In Integration with Swift 3](https://www.simplifiedios.net/google-sign-integration-ios/)**